# Can't use created gem on computer

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I created a gem with the following gemspec file.

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'SomeToken'
  s.version     = '0.0.0'
  s.date        = '2013-08-04'
  s.summary     = "A gem for use with SomeToken."
  s.description = "A gem for use with SomeToken."
  s.authors     = ["Jason Tanner"]
  s.email       = 'jasontanner328@gmail.com'
  s.files       = Dir.glob '**/*'
  s.homepage    = ''
  s.license     = ''
end
```

Then in my terminal I run

```
gem build sometoken.gemspec
```

Then,

```
gem install ./SomeToken-0.0.0.gem
```

The gem is successfully installed, so when I run irb and I run...

```
require 'SomeToken'
```

Which responds with the error

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- SomeToken
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I've tried changing the casing for the string, in numerous combinations but still get the same error. What's wrong with my gem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require 'some_token'`.

#### Using require in general

`require` takes the name of a ruby file, not the name of a gem. For example, if you have the following directory structure

```
- foo.rb
- main.rb
```

Then in `main.rb`, you can use `require 'foo'` to use stuff from `foo.rb`.

#### Using require with gems

Notice that the first line of your gemspec has `$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)`. This adds the `lib` directory of your gem to the search path. Thus, if you have

```
lib/
  some_token.rb
```

then you should use `require 'some_token'`.

Comment: My directory was organized in a way that didn't match the file path. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Ruby 2.0.0 have this 'bug', but some Ruby versions must have a

```
require 'rubygems'
```

before you require any gem.

Guess it's worth a try :)

Comment: Doesn't do anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.